# Find the implicite and explicite set of this little cartesian product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis, systems-of-equations

> $S$ is the set of all $(x_{1},x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$
>   with $x_{1}+x_{2} \geq 3$ and $-x_{1}+2x_{2}=6$
>
> What's its implicit and explicit set?

Implicite: $S=\left\{(x_{1},x_{2})|x_{1},x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

For the explicite we somehow have to calculate the solutions for $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ (?) The problem is there is this inequality sign...

$$-x_{1}+2x_{2}=6$$

$$x_{1}=2x_{2}-6$$

Now take the other formula and replace $x_{1}$:

$$2x_{2}-6+x_{2} \geq 3$$

$$3x_{2}-6 \geq 3$$

$$x_{2} \geq 3$$

Now we need to find out $x_{1}$:

$$x_{1}+x_{2} \geq 3$$

$$x_{1} \geq 0$$

This means the explicite set would be: $S=\left\{x_{1} \geq 0, x_{2} \geq 3\right\}$

---

Please can you tell me, did I do it correctly? I have my doubts because none of the sets I have calculated include both the given formulas...

Comment: You're proposing that the intersection of a line with a half plane is a quarter plane. Does that sound right? No. $(3,3)$ is in your final set, but it does not satisfy the line equation.

Comment: How do you even write explicit sets when they are infinite? I've actually never Seen this distinction before and it doesn't seem terribly useful.

Comment: Oh you are right, thanks! Now I see and I also see the problem you mentioned. (3,3) works for the second but not the first formula.. : /
Well this is a task but how else can we solve this? Is the implicite set i wrote above correct by the way?

Comment: you implicit set is all of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, and this is just as obviously incorrect. I won't be of much help until I understand what an acceptable "explicit set" solution looks like. The implicit set solution is barely different from the given, so that should be easy. In both cases, I don't see much point to the exercise.

Comment: Explicit set means you write the solutions into the set, for example you have a function given and are supposed to make explicit and implicit set. Implicit set would be the general one where you say the definition of the function. Here is similar question I asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979050/write-this-set-implicitly-and-explicitly-s-1-is-the-set-of-the-zero-points?noredirect=1#comment4062905_1979050

Comment: as I asked earlier : how do you explicitly write out the elements of an infinite set? How do you explicitly write the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: Oh I think then there is no way since they are infinite..

Comment: Damn then this task is either very mean or just stupid.. or both. Anyway how would the implicit look then? As I did above, you said it's wrong but how to do it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a better way to write this with set-builder notation than

$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\mid x_1+x_2\geq 3 \text{ and } -x_1+2x_2=6\}$$

Or

$$\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\mid x_1+x_2\geq 3 \}\cap\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\mid -x_1+2x_2=6\} $$

As discussed in the comments, nobody yet understands how you would write this set explicitly since it has infinitely many elements.