# What is the implicite set of this function: $f(x)=x^2-2x-6$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

What would be its implicite set, I have troubles writing it.

I would write it like that:

$$S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x^{2}-2x-6=0 \right \}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the implicite set?

Comment: Hmm it is a general set describing the function in general.. Explicite would be where you write both of the solutions in the set and this is very easy. But how the implicite? Please help me if you can.

Comment: If with "implict set" you are meaning the set of values satisfying a certain "condition", then you have to specify if the condition is the *equation* $x^2−2x−6=0$ or the *function* $x^2−2x−6$. In the first case, the condition selects the roots of the equation, while in the second case this is not so : for every number $z$ we may compute the value of $f(z)$.

Comment: $$S=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x^{2}-2x-6 \right \}$$?

Comment: See [truth set](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/truth+set).

Comment: I don`t understand please just say yes or no I have to hand it in now :(

Comment: I think it looks better now.

Comment: According to your previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980264/find-the-implicite-and-explicite-set-of-this-little-cartesian-product), the implicit set for a "condition" $\varphi$ is the set $S = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$. If e.g. $\varphi$ is $x \in A$, then the corresponding implicit set $S_A = \{ x \mid x \in A \}$.